# Display chess board from svg file in kivy python

Tags: python, svg, kivy

I'm trying to display a chessboard with pieces from an svg file but the result is not what I expected. The chessboard is printed without the pieces in place. The pieces appear in a corner one on top of the other. If I print the svg file in a Jupyter Notebook, the board is displayed correctly.

### Output from my Kivy App

[image: Output from my script]

### Output from Jupyter Notebook

[image: Output from Jupyter Notebook]

I use macOS Mojave, python 3.7 and kivy 1.11.

### Python Script

```
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics.svg import Svg
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
#from IPython.display import SVG

Builder.load_string("""
<SvgWidget>:
    do_rotation: False
<FloatLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: (1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
""")

#SVG(filename="../testchess/boards/board_0.1.7.svg") 
class SvgWidget(Scatter):

    def __init__(self, filename, **kwargs):
        super(SvgWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            svg = Svg(filename)
        self.size = svg.width, svg.height


class SvgApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = FloatLayout()

        filename = "../testchess/boards/board_0.1.7.svg"
        svg = SvgWidget(filename, size_hint=(None, None), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1})
        self.root.add_widget(svg)
        svg.scale = 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SvgApp().run()
```

### svg

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><g class="white rook" fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd" id="white-rook" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5"><path d="M9 39h27v-3H9v3zM12 36v-4h21v4H12zM11 14V9h4v2h5V9h5v2h5V9h4v5" stroke-linecap="butt" /><path d="M34 14l-3 3H14l-3-3" /><path d="M31 17v12.5H14V17" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" /><path d="M31 29.5l1.5 2.5h-20l1.5-2.5" /><path d="M11 14h23" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="miter" /></g><g class="white king" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" id="white-king" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5"><path d="M22.5 11.63V6M20 8h5" stroke-linejoin="miter" /><path d="M22.5 25s4.5-7.5 3-10.5c0 0-1-2.5-3-2.5s-3 2.5-3 2.5c-1.5 3 3 10.5 3 10.5" fill="#fff" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" /><path d="M11.5 37c5.5 3.5 15.5 3.5 21 0v-7s9-4.5 6-10.5c-4-6.5-13.5-3.5-16 4V27v-3.5c-3.5-7.5-13-10.5-16-4-3 6 5 10 5 10V37z" fill="#fff" /><path d="M11.5 30c5.5-3 15.5-3 21 0m-21 3.5c5.5-3 15.5-3 21 0m-21 3.5c5.5-3 15.5-3 21 0" /></g></defs><rect class="square dark a1" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="20" y="335" /><use transform="translate(20, 335)" xlink:href="#white-rook" /><rect class="square light b1" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="65" y="335" /><rect class="square dark c1" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="110" y="335" /><rect class="square light d1" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="155" y="335" /><rect class="square dark e1" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="200" y="335" /><use transform="translate(200, 335)" xlink:href="#white-king" /><rect class="square light f1" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="245" y="335" /><rect class="square dark g1" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="290" y="335" /><rect class="square light h1" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="335" y="335" /><use transform="translate(335, 335)" xlink:href="#white-rook" /><rect class="square light a2" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="20" y="290" /><rect class="square dark b2" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="65" y="290" /><rect class="square light c2" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="110" y="290" /><rect class="square dark d2" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="155" y="290" /><rect class="square light e2" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="200" y="290" /><rect class="square dark f2" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="245" y="290" /><rect class="square light g2" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="290" y="290" /><rect class="square dark h2" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="335" y="290" /><rect class="square dark a3" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="20" y="245" /><rect class="square light b3" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="65" y="245" /><rect class="square dark c3" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="110" y="245" /><rect class="square light d3" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="155" y="245" /><rect class="square dark e3" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="200" y="245" /><rect class="square light f3" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="245" y="245" /><rect class="square dark g3" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="290" y="245" /><rect class="square light h3" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="335" y="245" /><rect class="square light a4" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="20" y="200" /><rect class="square dark b4" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="65" y="200" /><rect class="square light c4" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="110" y="200" /><rect class="square dark d4" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="155" y="200" /><rect class="square light e4" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="200" y="200" /><rect class="square dark f4" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="245" y="200" /><rect class="square light g4" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="290" y="200" /><rect class="square dark h4" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="335" y="200" /><rect class="square dark a5" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="20" y="155" /><rect class="square light b5" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="65" y="155" /><rect class="square dark c5" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="110" y="155" /><rect class="square light d5" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="155" y="155" /><rect class="square dark e5" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="200" y="155" /><rect class="square light f5" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="245" y="155" /><rect class="square dark g5" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="290" y="155" /><rect class="square light h5" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="335" y="155" /><rect class="square light a6" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="20" y="110" /><rect class="square dark b6" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="65" y="110" /><rect class="square light c6" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="110" y="110" /><rect class="square dark d6" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="155" y="110" /><rect class="square light e6" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="200" y="110" /><rect class="square dark f6" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="245" y="110" /><rect class="square light g6" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="290" y="110" /><rect class="square dark h6" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="335" y="110" /><rect class="square dark a7" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="20" y="65" /><rect class="square light b7" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="65" y="65" /><rect class="square dark c7" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="110" y="65" /><rect class="square light d7" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="155" y="65" /><rect class="square dark e7" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="200" y="65" /><rect class="square light f7" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="245" y="65" /><rect class="square dark g7" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="290" y="65" /><rect class="square light h7" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="335" y="65" /><rect class="square light a8" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="20" y="20" /><rect class="square dark b8" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="65" y="20" /><rect class="square light c8" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="110" y="20" /><rect class="square dark d8" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="155" y="20" /><rect class="square light e8" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="200" y="20" /><rect class="square dark f8" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="245" y="20" /><rect class="square light g8" fill="#ffce9e" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="290" y="20" /><rect class="square dark h8" fill="#d18b47" height="45" stroke="none" width="45" x="335" y="20" /><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="42" y="10">a</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="42" y="390">a</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="87" y="10">b</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="87" y="390">b</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="132" y="10">c</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="132" y="390">c</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="177" y="10">d</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="177" y="390">d</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="222" y="10">e</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="222" y="390">e</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="267" y="10">f</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="267" y="390">f</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="312" y="10">g</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="312" y="390">g</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="357" y="10">h</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="357" y="390">h</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="10" y="357">1</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="390" y="357">1</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="10" y="312">2</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="390" y="312">2</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="10" y="267">3</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="390" y="267">3</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="10" y="222">4</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="390" y="222">4</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="10" y="177">5</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="390" y="177">5</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="10" y="132">6</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="390" y="132">6</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="10" y="87">7</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="390" y="87">7</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="10" y="42">8</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" x="390" y="42">8</text></svg>
```

I expect a chessboard with the pieces in place.

Comment: Probably Kivy's svg parser has a bug or missing feature relating to some of the contents of your svg.