# Integrating chess-svg texture into kivy object

Tags: python, kivy, python-chess

Previously I have had success in integrating bytes of png files into a kivy image using the `obj.texture` reference. I am currently trying to do this with a `chess.svg` string but am not having much success. MWE below:

```
# dependencies

import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.image import Image as UIXImage
from kivy.uix.behaviors.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

import chess
import chess.svg


# chess-related vars

myimg = str( chess.svg.board( board=chess.Board() ) ) #svg code


# custom chess-board obj

class ChessBoard(ButtonBehavior, UIXImage):

    boardimg = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self,boardimg,**kwargs):
        super(ChessBoard,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.boardimg = boardimg
        self.render()

    def render(self,*args):

        print(self.boardimg) # TODO manipulate myimg into a texture-rippable obj

        # self.texture = myimg.texture

        pass


# build the app

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ChessBoard(myimg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Any insight on how to make this work would be much appreciated, as it appears to be a gap in our collective community knowledge (e.g., see: [Display chess board from svg file in kivy python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56684340/display-chess-board-from-svg-file-in-kivy-python)). One of my design goals with this code is to do the entire integration without having to save any image files locally, so that rules out kivy's `SvgWidget` unless there is a way to use it without referencing a file.

Comment: i wish there was an answer to this

Comment: @Nv7 me too, until then this is... stale, mate

Comment: Were you ever able to move/scale the svg?

Comment: I did not get much further than this unfortunately, but if you want to start a repo and see if we can hack something together, DM me and let's see what we can do

Comment: I believe you can actually generate an image file, make an SVG Object out of it, and then delete the file immediately. That is what I am doing. But I was still unable to scale and move it.

Comment: I was able to move the svg, but still not scale it.

Comment: Yes I just invited you to a git repository, let's pick this up over there (and once we have found a solution, you get first dibs on answering this question!)

Comment: I was able to scale the SVG, but it appears that text cannot be rendered. I think I am going to look into some other method of rendering SVG with Kivy

Comment: Where did you invite me? Could you send a link? Thanks!

Comment: @Nv7 Did you ever get the Python-Chess chessboard to render and scale so it is usable to play chess on? If so, please post the code for all to see!